# My Ggplots are formatting the date incorrectly (sorting by year when in the format %m/%y)

Tags: r, ggplot2, as.date

```
countrydf$dates <- format(as.Date(countrydf$date, format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%m/%y", ordered = T)
germanydf <- subset(countrydf,location == "Germany")
ggplot(germanydf, aes(x=dates, y=total_deaths)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
 geom_smooth(method="lm", col="Grey", size=1) + 
  labs(title="Deaths vs date in Germany", subtitle="From ourworldindata.org", y="Total Deaths", x="Date")  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=.5))
```

[image]

Even though I formatted as a date, I am still getting the dates as "01/2020, 01/2021, 01/2022" (incorrect) vs "01/2020, 02/2020, 03/2020" (correct). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As well, when viewing the dataframe, they are ordered correctly, so it is clearly a Ggplot formatting thing.

[image]

Comment: Please give us a full example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details. Otherwise we can only guess what is happening here.

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. Use comments for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `format()`  returns a string, not a date. Thus, you get strings that are of the format `01/2020`, `02/2020` etc. Naturally, these strings, when sorted, are not sorted by date – but just like any string, alphanumerically, and `01/2021` comes before `02/2020`.

What exactly is happening? When ggplot takes your variable as X, it converts it to a factor, because it is a categorical (as opposed to continuous) variables. By default, factor levels are sorted alphanumerically.

Solutions:

- drop the `format` function. ggplot understands dates. If you want, you can drop the day from the date (e.g. using lubridate).
- change the date column to factor and specify levels manually.
- format date starting with year.

Comment: No problem. However, please do remove your answer to that question; these answers here are not for comments / discussion ;-) Also, if you are happy with someones answer, please do upvote / accept it.